# Unable to bring up vagrant box image which was added with parameter --name

Tags: vagrant

I downloaded the Vagrant box image directly using the URL and then added them using the --name option as

```
    C:\Users\vnathan>vagrant box add --name monasca c:\Users\vnathan\.vagrant\machines\monasca\devstack\virtualbox\devstack-0.1.3.box
```

and I was able to see the directory with vmdk file, manifest.json file, Vagrantfile, OVA file.
under the directory C:\Users\vnathan.vagrant.d\boxes\monasca\0\virtualbox

I was able to able to view the list of added box on running

```
       C:\Users\vnathan>vagrant box list
       monasca (virtualbox, 0)
```

but I was not able to bring up the vagrant box on running the vagrant up command.

```
      C:\Users\vnathan>vagrant up monasca
      The machine with the name 'monasca' was not found configured for this Vagrant environment.
```

I updated the `config.vm.box = "monasca"` in the main `Vagrantfile` but still I could not bring up the instance.

Please let me know what should I do to poweron the box on running vagrant up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The box setting is correct, show me the `Vagrantfile`, I guess there are something wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks BMW; I tried below steps on going thru some of the sites and finally I was able to add monasca box as part of vagrant but VirtualBox fails to import the image; I need to now dig in to resolve this issue.

```
C:\Users\vnathan>vagrant status
Current machine states:

     default                   not created (virtualbox)

     The environment has not yet been created. Run `vagrant up` to
     create the environment. If a machine is not created, only the
     default provider will be shown. So if a provider is not listed,
     then the machine is not created for that environment.
```

On Running vagrant up

```
C:\Users\vnathan>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'monasca'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "C:/Users/vnathan/.vagrant.d/boxes/monasca/0/virtualbox/box.
ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "ds-build_devstack_1412364613065_73348_14187919
33520_71376", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "7", "--disk", "C:\\Users\\vnathan\\Virtu
alBox VMs\\ds-build_devstack_1412364613065_73348_1418791933520_71376\\box-disk1.
vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting C:\Users\vnathan\.vagrant.d\boxes\monasca\0\virtualbox\box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the clone medium 'C:\Users\vnathan\Virtu
alBox VMs\ds-build_devstack_1412364613065_73348_1418791933520_71376\box-disk1.vm
dk'.
VBoxManage.exe: error: VMDK: Compressed image is corrupted 'C:\Users\vnathan\.va
grant.d\boxes\monasca\0\virtualbox\box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_ZIP_CORRUPTED)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component A
ppliance, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "int __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct Handle
rArg *)" at line 779 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```